# ArcMap 10.5 graticule incorrectly displays positive long tick labels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, grids-graticules

In ArcMap 10.5 I created a map of my study site and added a graticule. I realized that the longitude tick labels are missing the "-" sign e.g., displayed label 79°19'W should actually be -79°19'W, since it's western hemisphere.

How can I correct this in the graticule options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the setting in 10.7. Hopefully the same in 10.5.

[image: ArcMap 10.7 Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for showing this. I had this setting on "Show coordinate direction labels" (i guess this is the default since i did not touch it). When i untoggled it, i was able to select the bottom option. Now it works. Excellent!